# Why IdentityHashMap.keySet().removeAll(keys) does not use identity? Is it a bug?

Tags: java, identity, removeall

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IdentityHashMap<Integer, Object> m1 = new IdentityHashMap<Integer, Object>();
    Integer ONE = 1;
    Integer TWO = 2;
    Integer OTHER_ONE = new Integer(1);
    Integer OTHER_TWO = new Integer(2);
    m1.put(ONE, new Object());
    m1.put(TWO, new Object());
    System.out.println(m1.keySet()); // [1, 2]

    m1.remove(OTHER_ONE); // Does not remove
    System.out.println(m1.keySet()); // [1, 2]

    m1.remove(ONE); // Does remove
    System.out.println(m1.keySet()); // [2]

    m1.keySet().removeAll(Arrays.asList(OTHER_TWO)); // ...
    System.out.println(m1.keySet()); // [] WHAT?
}
```

Reference here [IdentityHashMap.keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html#keySet%28%29)

I found an answer in the source code (see below) but I don't know the ultimate reason. Is it a bug?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021374/boxed-primitives-and-equivalence/2021442.

Comment: Danstahr i know that. I use new Integer() there intentionally to test identity behaviour of the map. I am asking about removeAll. Is the question not clear? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this source code from java 1.7.0_11

```
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean modified = false;
        for (Iterator<K> i = iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            if (c.contains(i.next())) {
                i.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }
        return modified;
    }
```

It is using c.contains() so the behaviour depends on the collection class. I didn't understand that from the javadoc.

I found out it is a bug reported 6 years ago and still unresolved!!
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6588783

Comment: There is a question in that answer, so maybe incorporate it into the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. It will illustrate what happened.

```
  System.out.println(OTHER_ONE == ONE);
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(OTHER_ONE).contains( ONE));
```

OTHER_ONE is the object that will in the heap memory. ONE is not an object so it resides in the constant pool memory.

if you create Wrapper Objects with `new keyword` then only it will go to heap memory otherwise it will saved in the constant pool.

Comment: Because that's not what the question is about

Comment: My -1 is because it does not answer the question and ONE is an object too but you insist (don't edit) to say it is not what may confuse other programmers.