# Java == strange behavior

Tags: java, equality

I wanted to check Integer equality in my application but came across a strange behavior. At some point my application was working correctly but at some point it was failing. So I just written a test code over here

```
public class EqualityTest {

     public static void main(String args[]) {
           Integer a = 100;
           Integer b = 100;
           Integer c = 1000;
           Integer d = 1000;
           if (a == b) {
                 System.out.println("a & b are Equal");
           }
           else {
                 System.out.println("a & b are Not Equal");
           }

           if (c == d) {
                 System.out.println("c & d are Equal");
           } else {
                 System.out.println("c & d are Not Equal");
           }
     }
}
```

Output

```
a & b are Equal
c & d are Not Equal
```

here my question is why c and d are not equal?

Comment: lower value caching in Integer

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java

Comment: oh! yes got the answer. I need to use equals.

Comment: also related answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20877115/2817802)

Comment: upto 127 it show equal there after not equal

Comment: Refer java docs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html.
public static Integer valueOf(int i) its since 1.5

Answer (score 6):

`Integer` uses ***caching*** of small values in range of -128 to 127, and so you get same instance for small values such as 100.

For the values outside this range, a new `Integer` instance is created and returned.

Comment: and the cached value is between -128 to 127.. Anything within this range, you get the same object (so 100 gives equal.) and anything outside this range, a new object is returned (2 new Integer objects with value 1000 .. So you get false..)

Answer (score 3):

Integer is mutable class and keep around -128 to 127 integers in cache. So == will work on Integers `-128 <= i <= 127`

Each time you create Integer with this range it will return you the same object previously created.

For **Java 7** implementation could be achieved with system property:

```
-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=<size>
```

Answer (score -3):

Integer is an Object.
You should use equal instead of == 
like

```
if(a.equal(b)){
...
}
```

Comment: Doesnt answer the question.. OP already knows this...

Comment: this is not in the complete answer: please address caching of small values.

Answer (score -4):

```
        Integer a = 100;
        Integer b = 100;
        Integer c = 1000;
        Integer d = 1000;
        if (a.equals(b)) {
            System.out.println("a & b are Equal");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("a & b are Not Equal");
        }
        if (c.equals(d)) {
            System.out.println("c & d are Equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("c & d are Not Equal");
        }
```

==means their pointer or reference equal,not value equal.You should call .equals method

Comment: this is not in the complete answer: please address caching of small values.