# == operator return false if compare Double type with the same value

Tags: java, equals, autoboxing

Why equal method is false when I compare two double primitive types with the same value? However integer is not

```
public class EqualMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Double value1 = 6.2;
        Double value2 = 6.2;        
        System.out.println(value1 == value2);

        Integer number1 = 2;
        Integer number2 = 2;
        System.out.println(number1 == number2);  
    } 
}
```

Comment: `equals()` is for comparing objects, `==` for raw data types.

Comment: BTW, try doing `Double value1 = Double.valueOf(6.2); Double value2 = Double.valueOf(6.2);` since there's no need to allocate two `Double` objects to represent the same value. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28double%29).

Comment: these are not primitives

Comment: @2rs2ts: what you wrote is exactly equivalent to the original code. And it does allocate two different instances, otherwise, value1 would be equal to value2.

Comment: @2rs2ts he is not using `new Double(6.2)` (which DOES allocate new object) so I doubt `valueOf` has any advantage; it's only clutter

Comment: @JBNizet "If a new Double instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Double(double), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values." So are you saying it would allocate two instances anyway?

Comment: @elmes All right, I didn't realize it wouldn't help.

Comment: Let's not forget the second half of the question - why this isn't the case for `Integer` (i.e., if the code read `Integer value1 = 6; Integer value2 = 6;` then the condition would be true).  To address that, you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/20877086/1081110 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1514910/1081110, each of which have two excellent answers.

Comment: Yes, it would. 6.2 is far from being a frequently requested value. And `Double d = 6.2` **is** compiled to `Double d = Double.valueOf(6.2)`, not to `Double d = new Double(6.2)`. So your code is a more verbose way of writing the exact same thing as the OP. Also note that the actual implementation of valueOf() is... `return new Double(d)`

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for explaining. I was ignorant :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing references and not values. Either do:

`value1.equals(value2);`

or do:

`value1.doubleValue() == value2.doubleValue();`

Read more about [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) here to figure out why this works sometimes (with integers) and why sometimes it does not. Notice that **all integers** are a summation of a power of 2: 6 = 2 + 4, whereas decimals are not: 6.2 = 4 + 2 + 1/8 + ...

Comment: Or just replace `Double` by `double`.

Comment: @BalusC Yes,that's my answer :)

Comment: how about Integer with the same value why it is true ?

Comment: `Integer` (and all other non-fp `Number` implementations) uses [Flyweight pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2707195) for values between -128 en 127. Try a number outside this range :)

Comment: @Durdona `Integer` is a little different, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-integer-boxing-in-java for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Both variables are initialized by a boxing conversion to a `Double` object.  When using `==` on objects, the references are compared if they are the same object, and the contents are not compared.

To compare the contents, you can use either the [`equals` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), or you can check if the result of calling [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo-java.lang.Double-) is equal to `0`.  Or, you can declare both variables as `double`, and then `==` will compare the values directly.

Answer (score 0):

`==`   Meant for reference comparison

`.equals` Meant for content comparison

1.In your code two objects will be created with  references `value1` and `value2` pointing to different object.If you use `value1==value2` it will return `false`.If references points to same object it will return `true`

```
Double value1 = 6.2;
Double value2 = 6.2;
```

2.If you use `value1.equals(value2)` it will compare the content of the objects which will return  `true`