# Java interview: for loop, object/class reference and bound limit

Tags: java, class, object, for-loop

This question came up in one of my interview questions for an internship position written in Java.
Notice that the boolean function `isSame` actually declares 2 parameters as `Integer` class - not `int`, so I thought `a` and `b` are objects, correct?

```
public class ForLoop{

 public static boolean isSame(Integer a, Integer b) {
     return a == b;
 }

 public static void main(String []args){

    int i = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<500; ++j) {
        if (isSame(i,j)) {
            System.out.println("Same i = "+i);
            System.out.println("Same j = "+j);
            ++i;
            continue;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Different i = "+i);
            System.out.println("Different j = "+j);
            ++i;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final i = " + i);

 }
}
```

My first thought is that the `for` loop would terminate in the 1st run with the result `Final i = 1`,
but to my surprise the final output is `i = 129`. The loop terminated when both i & j = 128.

```
  Same i = 126
  Same j = 126
  Same i = 127
  Same j = 127
  Different i = 128
  Different j = 128
  Final i = 129
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: [The answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877086/confusion-in-method-integer-valueofstring) will answer your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When testing `Object` types for equality use `.equals()`, as you have found -128 to 127 (inclusive) are pooled. The [JLS-5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) says in part,

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an `int` or `short` number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.