# Why == for Integer.valueOf(500) returns false but true for 5?

Tags: java, oop, integer

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(5) == Integer.valueOf(5));
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(500) == Integer.valueOf(500));
```

The output is

```
true
false
```

Why does the first line returns true but the second line returns false? What's the trick here since both are calling `valueOf()` on `Integer` class.

Comment: this is comparing pointers and not integers. The fact that for 5, it returns the same pointer is just an optimization, an implementation detail. (FYI, I don't know any Java at all, I just [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20877086

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's cached instances of low numbered Integer objects but not any of higher valued Integer objects.

If you didn't notice before, you are comparing objects, not ints.