# Greater than or equals to always trigger

Tags: android

Here is the code in question:

```
public void setReminder() {
    if (db.getTotalIncome(prefs.getString("username", "")) != 0.0 ||
        db.getTotalExpenses(prefs.getString("username", "")) != 0.0 ||
        db.getReminder(prefs.getString("username", "")) != null) {

        Float income = db.getTotalIncome(prefs.getString("username", ""));
        Float expense = db.getTotalExpenses(prefs.getString("username", ""));
        Cursor reminder = db.getReminder(prefs.getString("username", ""));
        if (reminder.moveToFirst() != false) {
            String reminderValue = reminder.getString(reminder.getColumnIndex("value"));
            if (expense <= Integer.parseInt(reminderValue)/100*income) {
                PugNotification.with(this)
                    .load()
                    .title("Warning")
                    .message("Expenses nearing threshold")
                    .bigTextStyle("You have spent more than " + Integer.parseInt(reminderValue) / 100 + "% " + "of your income!")
                    .smallIcon(R.drawable.icon_flag)
                    .largeIcon(R.drawable.icon_flag)
                    .flags(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .simple()
                    .build();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, at `if (expense <= Integer.parseInt(reminderValue)/100*income)`, it always seem to be true, causing the notification to show up. I can't seem to figure out what is going on. Another thing, it seems like the first `if` statement

```
if (db.getTotalIncome(prefs.getString("username", "")) != 0.0 ||
    db.getTotalExpenses(prefs.getString("username", "")) != 0.0 ||
    db.getReminder(prefs.getString("username", "")) != null)
```

Also always return true. I read up that default value for float is 0.0, so is my code wrong or what is going on?

Comment: Simple solution :- Use Debugger . You will get `what is going on`.

Comment: Found the problem: `Integer.parseInt(reminderValue)/100` returns 0 all the time. Changing it to `Float.valueOf(reminderValue)` solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
    if (db.getTotalIncome(prefs.getString("username", "")) != 0.0 ||
            db.getTotalExpenses(prefs.getString("username", "")) != 0.0 ||
            db.getReminder(prefs.getString("username", "")) != null)
```

The expression inside if is always true because you're using `||` which means `or` so if any of the arguments is true the whole expression is true. In your case at least one of the arguments is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
expense.intValue() <= Integer.parseInt(reminderValue)/100*income
```

Same for your other if statement:

```
if (db.getTotalIncome(prefs.getString("username", "")).intValue() != 0 ||
                db.getTotalExpenses(prefs.getString("username", "")).intValue() != 0 ||
                db.getReminder(prefs.getString("username", "")) != null)
```

For more information read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139595/284308

Comment: Nope doesn't work, in debugging mode and this statement always evaluates to false