# Why 'if' statement is giving false result on comparing two indexes of arraylist even they have same value

Tags: java, arraylist

Today I found strange thing about ArrayList. For the following program:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al.add(128);
    al.add(128);
    int t1 = al.get(0);
    int t2 = al.get(1);
    if(al.get(0)== al.get(1))
      System.out.print("true");
    else
      System.out.print("false");
    if(t1== t2)
      System.out.print("true");
    else
      System.out.print("false");
```

It it is giving result as falsetrue. For value less than 128, it is giving truetrue. I don't understand what is the logic behind it?

Comment: Try reading the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/20877086 if you want to understand why 128 is different from the lesser numbers.

Comment: Oh forgot that Integer is an object so didn't use equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Language Specification says that the wrapper objects for at least -128 to 127 are cached and reused.