# Java Integer Identity

Tags: java, object, identity

I'm looking into the identity of integers, I know an Object is identical to another Object when they occupy the same memory space, it can be shown by the following code

```
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = a;
System.out.println(a == b);
```

this will return `true` because the reference `b` is pointing to `a`, when looking at equality there are conditions that needs to be met for any Object to be equal to another, using the following code

```
Integer a = 1000;
Integer b = 1000;
System.out.println(a == b);
```

this will return `false` because `a` and `b` are two different objects, and this makes sense, but here is where I get confused, if I write

```
    Integer a = 1;
    Integer b = 1;

    Integer c = 1000;
    Integer d = 1000;

    System.out.println(a == b);

    System.out.println(c == d);
```

the first print will return `true` and the last will return `false`, since all four integers are different objects, they should return `false`, why does the first return `true` ? I looked at the `Integer.valueOf()` method (based on my knowledge of boxing and unboxing) and found that once a value is bigger than 128 (1 Byte) its cached differently, why is that? can anyone perhaps explain this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-integer-boxing-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20877086