# Integer.valueOf() confusion

Tags: java, integer, value-of

On a slide in this [Presentation on Project Valhalla](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/java-valhalla-inline-types/) (around 4:00) i stumbled across this Java gotcha:

```
Integer.valueOf(42) == Integer.valueOf(42);
```

**BUT**

```
Integer.valueOf(420) != Integer.valueOf(420);
```

Can somebody explain?

Comment: this is comparing the object, not value. so you have to use the equals method

Comment: @FaizAkram yeah i know - but still that doesn't explain why one evaluates to true and the other doesn't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877086/why-do-comparisons-with-integer-valueofstring-give-different-results-for-12#answer-20877283 does though.

Comment: the values 0..255 are cached always returning the same value and from 256 onwards a new value is created thats why are different.