# Wrapper class and Reference

Tags: java

What is difference between following?

```
Integer i1=new Integer(10);
Integer i2=new Integer(10);
```

System.out.println(i1==i2) //output is false
//means that i1 and i2 does not have same refernce
but when i do

```
Integer i1=10;
Integer i2=10;
```

System.out.println(i1==i2) //output is true
//means that i1 and i2 have same reference 
why is it so?

Comment: This discussion might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306853/behavior-of-wrapper-class-in-java and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching

Comment: Integer values between -128, 127 are cached and since you are not using keyword new, references point to the same cached object.