# Return false when checking same Integer value using two different HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I couldn't understand why it's printing false when HashMap key is `2`

```
Map<Integer, Integer> first = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

Map<Integer, Integer> second = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

first.put(1, 10);
second.put(1, 10);

first.put(2, 155);
second.put(2, 155);

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    System.out.print("first=" + first.get(i) + "," + "second="
            + second.get(i) + " ");
    System.out.println(first.get(i) == second.get(i));

}
```

Result

```
first=10,second=10 true
first=155,second=155 false
```

Comment: An instance of `Integer` for values between `-128` and `127` is cached. So the values `10` are the exact same instance. That's not the case for `155`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does 128==128 return false but 127==127 return true in this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-in-this-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
System.out.println(first.get(i) == second.get(i));
```

*no unboxing takes place*.

Both sides of the `==` operator are `Object` instances; therefore, what will be performed is an object reference equality.

The first case, with `10`, only works "by luck".

Basically, what happens is that when you:

```
first.put(1, 10);
```

what is really called, because of boxing, is:

```
first.put(Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(10));
```

Now, it so happens that the `Integer` class has an inline cache which covers all values from -128 up to 127 *at least*, as the [javadoc of `Integer.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) explains:

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

But 155 is greater than 127; which means that this method is not required to cache it, in which case a *new* `Integer` instance will be created. And this is what happens here.

Comment: Are you sure about that last point? The docs for `valueOf` says -128 to 127 are always cached, but other values might be too.

Answer (score 0):

That's what [JLS 15.21.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) told you about your behavior:

> At run time, the result of == is true if the operand values are both
>   null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result
>   is false.