# different new String and new Integer in java?

Tags: java

```
String a="ABC";
String a2="ABC";

//--------------------------------------

String b=new String("ABC");    
String b2=new String("ABC");

//-----------------------------------------

int c=5;
int c2=5;

//-------------------------------------
int d=new Integer(5);    
int d2=new Integer(5);

//----------------------------------------
```

**a and a2** is pointer,memory same, **b and b2** is object not same memory, **a!=b, and b!=b2, why?** c=d and d=d2, new String is object and new Integer not object ?

Comment: Well, you stored `new Integer` in an `int`, so it got immediately unboxed.  If you had stored them in `Integer` variables it would have been different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> new String is object and new Integer not object

Because you immediately assigned the `Integer`s to a primitive type, not an object type.  If you had written

```
Integer d=new Integer(5);

Integer d2=new Integer(5);
```

then `d != d2` as expected, not least because the results of *any* two distinct invocations of `new` will be `!=` to each other.

Comment: You might add what happens due to `Integer a = 1; Integer b = 1; if( a == b )...;`

Comment: Eh.  For myself, I'd prefer what happens there to be a compile error.

Comment: @laune: As soon as you've used `==` to compare two objects with useful `.equals` implementations, you've done something wrong.

Comment: Now I understand your first comment. But testing for object identity is still necessary. You'd need another operator if == should cause a compile error.

Comment: Eh.  Objects that care about reference equality should inherit it in their `.equals` method, so you can use `.equals` everywhere.  There are extremely rare cases where it's necessary, so I could live with it being a suppressable warning.

Comment: No - you need the identity check in addition to equality. Independently.

Comment: Explain where that's actually necessary.

Comment: The javadoc for IdentityHashMap has a couple of applications. Also, see Drools for the difference between the two forms of equalsBehavior: identity and equality.

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1**

```
String a="ABC";
String a2="ABC";
```

This string will added in to **String Pool**

so when creating new String in String pool jvm do check whether the same string exists in string pool or not?, if exists the new string will refer the same string pool string

> So a and a2 point the same memory

**Case 2**

```
String b=new String("ABC");    
String b2=new String("ABC");
```

in this scenario new string object will be added. if you want point the same memory for above statement the you have to use like

```
String b=new String("ABC").intern();    
String b2=new String("ABC").intern();
```

> So b and b2 are not the same object

**Case 3**

```
    int c=5;
    int c2=5;
```

are primitives

**Case 4**

```
   int d=new Integer(5);    
   int d2=new Integer(5);
```

case 3 and case 4 you are comparing with  primitive value with Integer object reference values so it dors not match

> So your case also return false

References [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-in-this-code)

Comment: Your explanation for case 4  has a problem. There is no cache used if you create the instances using the `new` keyword. So `new Integer(5) == new Integer(5)` is `false`.