# Have I found a bug in Java Stack class? Why this two stack element is not the same??

Tags: java, stack, peek

I meet a really strang problem using Java Stack.

```
Stack<Integer> s=new Stack(), ss=new Stack();
s.push(1024);  ss.push(1024);
System.out.println(s.peek());
System.out.println(ss.peek());
System.out.println((s.peek()==ss.peek()));
System.out.println((s.peek()<ss.peek()));
System.out.println((s.peek()<=ss.peek()));
System.out.println((s.peek()!=ss.peek()));
```

See above code. 
But why the output is like this??

```
1024
1024
false
false
true
true
```

Is this a bug in Java?? Some one help....
Thanks, Kai

Comment: use `s.push(120);  ss.push(120);` instead and check your program ... ;). If you're confused now, then read this: [Why does 128==128 return false but 127==127 return true in this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-in-this-code)

Answer (score 7):

No, this is no bug and has nothing to do with `Stack` and all to do with the `Integer` class. Understand that Integer is a reference type and so two Integers can be `.equal(...)` and not `==`. Understand that when used on reference types `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The `equals(...)` method on the other hand checks if the values held by the two Integer objects are the same, and that's what matters here. This is similar to the situation we have with checking for String equality.

If you did:

```
// convert Integers to ints and test for primitive equality:
System.out.println((s.peek().intValue() == ss.peek().intValue()));
// or test using the equals(...) method
System.out.println((s.peek().equals(ss.peek()))); 
// or test with Integer#compareTo:
System.out.println((s.peek().compareTo(ss.peek()) == 0));
```

you'd get:

> true
>   true
>   true

Note also this interesting question: [Why does 128==128 return false but 127==127 return true in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-in-this-code). The answers explain why the check for equal references (i.e. `==` on reference types) on `Integer` variables returns `true` for a certain range of integer literals, like in this example:

```
System.out.println((Integer) 1024 == (Integer) 1024);
System.out.println((Integer) 127 == (Integer) 127);
```

prints:

> false
>   true

Comment: You might want to add, that the check of equal references with `==` works for a certain range of integer literals. Or close this questions as a duplicate :D. ... edit: oh, too late :D

Comment: @Tom: true, true. Will make a community wiki and close it.