# Java Stack peek() behavior

Tags: java, stack, peek

The following code returns `false` for all values except between -128 and 127. Is there any particular reason for this? I know I have to use `equals` because `peek()` returns a reference to the object, but I'm curious to know why it works only for the above range of values.

```
public boolean test(int x) {
    Stack<Integer> s1 = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> s2 = new Stack<Integer>();
    s1.push(x);
    s2.push(x);
    return (s1.peek() == s2.peek());
}
```

Comment: `Integer` caches values between -128 and 127 to improve performance.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-in-this-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons for this:

- autoboxing;
- the fact that [an `Integer` implementation, as per the documentation, has an internal cache of at least all values between, precisely, -128 and 127](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-).

When you autobox, `s1.push(x)` for some `int x` is transformed into `s1.push(Integer.valueOf(x))`. And since this is a cached value, the same instance is reused for any of these values.

Depending on the implementation of the JRE, `Integer` *may* have a larger cache than that as well -- but don't rely on that ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the lines

```
s1.push(x);
s2.push(x);
```

the primitive `int x` is autoboxed into an `Integer` instance using [`Integer.valueOf(x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) (java does that by itself). That method uses a Cache to store `Integer` instances in the range of -127 to 128, meaning that for all other `int` values, a new instance will be created in both of the lines of code above, resulting in the `==` comparison to return false.