# Some equal condition didn't work

Tags: java, equality

Why the equal operator dosn't work in this case :

```
Integer act0 = Integer.valueOf(ac.split("-")[0]);
if (activite_alerte.getActivite().getIdActivite() == act0)) {
    add_notif(profil, ao);
    added = true;
    break;
}
```

`activite_alerte.getActivite().getIdActivite()` and `act0` are equals  **439** but it didn't work but other value work.

Comment: use equals() instead of ==

Comment: Shouldn't you use `equals` ?

Comment: another one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-in-this-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-in-this-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a boxed integral type `Integer`. Java permits equality using `==` for values in the range -128 to +127 since these are "canned" boxed values, so a reference comparison will work for numbers in that range. But your number - 439 - is too big.

You should use `.equals()` instead for boxed types.

Personally I find this one of the most pernicious aspects of Java.

Answer (score 0):

consider the following program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer a = new Integer(1);
        Integer b = new Integer(1);
        System.out.println(a == b);
    }
}
```

The output of this program is `false`. for float and integer types java has primitive types (`int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, ...) which are not objects, and the object counterparts (`Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, ...), which are objects. When we write

```
int a = 3;
int b = 3;
```

The value `3` is assigned to two variables `a` and `b` of primitive types. the two variables can be tested for equality with `==`, which in this example will return `true`.

But if you write this:

```
Integer a = 3;
Integer b = 3;
```

Thanks to a feature called *autoboxing*, this is actually syntactic sugar for:

```
Integer a = new Integer(3);
Integer b = new Integer(3);
```

here we have two variables, each one referencing an object of class `Integer`. The two instances of `Integer` are distinct, even though semantically they reflect the same underlying int value. In java the `==` operator applied to variables referencing objects tests whether the two variable are *identical*, i.e. if they reference the same object instance. Hence

```
Integer a = 3;
Integer b = 3;
System.out.println(a == b);
```

will print `false`, as the two integer created by the autoboxing are distinct.  On the other side, this:

```
Integer a = 3;
Integer b = a;
System.out.println(a == b);
```

will print `true`, as `b` refers the same object created by autoboxing when `a` is declared.

In addition to testing for identity, for non-primitive variables you can test for *equality* using the `equals()` method. So this:

```
Integer a = 3;
Integer b = 3;
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

will print `true`. the `equals()` method is defined in the `Object` class, hence any class inherits. The one defined in `Object` checks for identity, but each subclass should override the method to provide the expected semantic. In the case of `Integer` for example, the redefinition checks the identity of the primitive member variable holding the integer value.