# String concatenation and comparision using ==

Tags: java

why the result is false?
could someone please explain?

```
public class StringTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a="a";
    String b=a+"b";
    String c="ab";
    System.out.println(b==c);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String a` is a reference to a String so when you do `b == c` you are comparing references to Strings and those references are not the same, even if the objects referenced contain the same data.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Here is a related common gotcha of using Java I recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-in-this-code

Comment: Note that the result might not be false if you declared `a` `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Because they don't point to the same object in the memory.

`==` is used for comparison of either primitive types, or object references.

What you want to do, is to compare their values, for which you 'll need to use the `equals(Object o)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(Object o)` method(s)

Answer (score 0):

> Output of this comparison is `FALSE` because you have created two
>   objects which have different location in heap so `==` compare their
>   reference or address location and return false.

Read more: http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/11/difference-between-operator-and-equals-method-in.html#ixzz3xmRzfSkP