# why i get the next output in my java code? (false true)

Tags: java

I think that the output should be (true true). Sorry for my english

```
  public class A{
     public static void main(String[] args)  {
       Integer i1 = 128;
       Integer i2 = 128;
       System.out.println(i1 == i2);

       Integer i3 = 127;
       Integer i4 = 127;
       System.out.println(i3 == i4);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a cache of `Integer` instances for a range of values (at least -128–127), that is used when implicitly converting an `int` to an `Integer`.

In this case, 128 is not in the cache, and so each `Integer` object representing that value is new and distinct.

The value 127, on the other hand, *is* guaranteed to be in the cache, and so the same instance of `Integer` is obtained repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Integer, as opposed to the primitive int, is an object.  Your comparison is comparing two objects of type Integer.  I'm kind of surprised you get "false true".  If you instead try:

```
System.out.println(i1.intValue() == i2.intValue());
System.out.println(i3.intValue() == i4.intValue());
```

you should get the expected result.

Comment: you, too, should read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-when-converting-to-integ

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.