# getDayOfWeek in ArrayList equals itself, but getYear does not

Tags: java, arraylist, localdate

Why does the following code print true with getDayOfWeek but false with getYear?

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    ArrayList<Object> dateData = new ArrayList<Object>();
    dateData.add(date.getDayOfWeek());
    dateData.add(date.getDayOfWeek());
    System.out.println( dateData.get(0) == dateData.get(1));  // prints true 

    dateData.clear();
    dateData.add(date.getYear());
    dateData.add(date.getYear());
    System.out.println( dateData.get(0) == dateData.get(1));  // prints false
```

Comment: `Integer` (Wrapper) cache.

Comment: Oh! of course... silly

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-when-converting-to-integ/1700117#1700117