# SQL query getting error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select query :

Select UID from att_value where Attributevalue="abc";

The output of this query is to be used to insert it into using the query :

Insert into useratt (ID,UID) Values ("123", output from the first query).

Can you please help me how to write a single query for this case.

Comment: Well did you try with other numbers before asking?

Comment: No, it's just `Integer`'s cache is only required to keep values from -128 to 127.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2001861/157247

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-when-converting-to-integ