# Two integer is equal but i am getting false

Tags: java

When I give some input for two values if they are equal ,it prints "True" in the terminal.But when both input is 128 I get false. Why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first number :");
    Integer number1 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
    Integer number2 = reader.nextInt();
    if (number1 == number2)
    {
        System.out.println("True");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("False");
    }
}
```

Input:

128

128

Output:(Should be)
True

But I get:

False

Comment: Integers are objects. `==` compares them by object identity (are these the same object) instead of value equality (represent these the same value).

Comment: == checks for object equality not the equality of values of objects. You can use compare method of Integer class.

Answer (score 1):

use `equals` instead of `==`:

```
if (number1.equals(number2)) {
    System.out.println("True");
}
else {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Comment: Any explaination, why == doesnt work after integer 128 ?

Comment: @yashpandey because it doesn't have to

Comment: I think here is some serious discussion about this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-when-converting-to-integ