# Do booleans auto-box to the same instance?

Tags: java, autoboxing

Do booleans auto-box to the same instance?

I have a little test that says they do, but I'm not going to stake anything on that. Is it guaranteed?

```
    @Test
    public void autoboxBooleans() {
        Multimap<Boolean, Integer> ids = HashMultimap.create();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Boolean rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean();
            ids.put(rand, System.identityHashCode(rand));
        }

        System.out.println(ids); // {false=[453523494], true=[2024918163]}
    }
```

**Note**: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081) talks about integers out of the range 0-127.

Comment: autoboxing makes use of the `valueOf()` methods on the classes of the respective primitives.  in many cases these are implemented to return already allocated instances.  however, you should _never_ rely on this behavior.

Comment: @jtahlborn unless, that is, [the documentation of the specific valueOf method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(boolean)) allows you to rely on it.

Comment: @AndyTurner sounds like it may depend on the version of the jvm (as the answers below indicate)

Comment: It is probably worth asking: why do you need to know? Relying on identity is rarely the right thing to do, especially for objects whose origin is unclear.

Comment: @AndyTurner I had to return millions of booleans in a generic interface and I didn't want useless garbage. I was wondering if I could avoid `return condition ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Java 11<sup>1</sup>, [JLS 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) states this:

> At run time, boxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> - If p is a value of type boolean, then boxing conversion converts p into a reference r of class and type Boolean, such that r.booleanValue() == p
>
> [...]
>
> If the value p being boxed **is the result of evaluating a constant expression (§15.28)** of type boolean, char, short, int, or long, and the result is true, false, a character in the range '\u0000' to '\u007f' inclusive, or an integer in the range -128 to 127 inclusive, then let a and b be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that a == b.

The JLS does not explicitly state that the `<wrapperType>::valueOf` method is used for autoboxing.  In practice, a Java compiler typically does implement it that way, but it is an implementation detail, and *could* (in theory) change.

So ... apart from the "constant expression" case ... you should NOT rely on autoboxed boolean values being identical to the `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE` object references<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Earlier versions of the JLS made a stronger statement about boxing.  But this is clearly a deliberate change to the spec.</sup>

<sup>2 - Your application could take steps to *manually* box boolean values using `Boolean::valueOf` (or some other way).  But that's a different scenario.  And probably not recommended, since you have to ensure that you do this consistently.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Note: This answer is correct for Java 7 and 8, Java 9-11 have a slightly different phrasing in the JLS.

---

Thanks to the comment by jtahlborn, I was able to research the answer.

[JLS 5.1.7 for Java 7&8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) says (emphasis mine)

> **If the value p being boxed is true, false**, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. **It is always the case that r1 == r2.**

For what it is worth, the javadoc for [Boolean#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-boolean-) says

> ... If the specified boolean value is true, this method returns Boolean.TRUE; if it is false, this method returns Boolean.FALSE....

Comment: That is for Java 7.  For Java 11, the JLS says something rather different!

Comment: @StephenC I saw that! and put a note. I've accepted your answer.