# Why the boxed Int shows unexpected behaviour on comparison?

Tags: kotlin

I don't understand why `boxedA === anotherBoxedA` returns **true**.

And `boxedB === anotherBoxedB` return **false**

```
    val a: Int = 100
    val boxedA: Int? = a
    val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
    val b: Int = 10000
    val boxedB: Int? = b
    val anotherBoxedB: Int? = b
    println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // true
    println(boxedB === anotherBoxedB) // false
}
```

Comment: Why are these named boxed? Kotlin doesn't have primitives.

Comment: It's written in the official documentation. the documentation is referring  them as boxed

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar It does, at least when targeting the JVM. If you just have `Int` then it uses the primitive `int` under-the-hood. But if you have something like `List<Int>` then it uses `List<Integer>` (i.e. a list of boxed integers) under-the-hood.

Comment: @Slaw I suppose you're referring to [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/) part of the docs _On the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are represented as values of the primitive type int._ What I meant is that the language doesn't have primitives; what it does at bytecode level shouldn't be reflected in the code because it makes no sense to those reading the code.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You should tell this to Kotlin's documentation authors then: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#numbers-representation-on-the-jvm

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Just did. There's a feedback form at the bottom of the page you referred to.

Comment: Can somebody explain why's the same question is asked over 5+ times? I swear I saw this alot within last two months.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Same teacher, perhaps? SO is the biggest homework dump these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    for (i in 1..10000) {
        val a: Int? = i
        val b: Int? = i
        
        val same = a === b
        if (!same) {
            println(i)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

> 128

[JLS, section 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7); object identity must be given for values -128 to 127 inclusive.

[Integer#valueOf(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) also documents this behavior:

> this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1700117/839733) answer for more details.