# Unboxing and Boxing in Java, but something feels strange

Tags: java, boxing, unboxing

```
        Integer a1=164;
        Integer a2=164;
        
        System.out.println(a1==a2);
        System.out.println(a1.equals(a2));

        Integer a3=new Integer(164);
        Integer a4=new Integer(164);
        
        System.out.println(a3==a4);
        System.out.println(a3.equals(a4));

This outputs as - 
false
true
false
true
```

BUT, same code with a slightly different input works in a different way

```
        Integer a1=64;
        Integer a2=64;
        
        System.out.println(a1==a2);
        System.out.println(a1.equals(a2));

        Integer a3=new Integer(64);
        Integer a4=new Integer(64);
        
        System.out.println(a3==a4);
        System.out.println(a3.equals(a4));

This outputs as -
true
true
false
true
```

I am sure somewhere the concept of unboxing is playing with me, but I cannot figure this out.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am not sure if we have a similar question, I did not find one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-is-128-128-false-but-127-127-is-true-when-comparing-integer-wrappers-in-ja

Comment: read about ```Integer caching```

Comment: `==` compare the reference(where the values are stored) not the values. So always use `.equals()` to compare reference type variable

Comment: Thanks everyone, I understood more on this topic by the link provided by @ArunSudhakaran
I was asked this in a interview on the name of autoboxing and unboxing, but looks it was more closely related to integer caching which is performed by JVM.