# Is it safe to use !=/== with Character?

Tags: java

Is it safe to use `==/!=` while comparing `Character`?

Character being a boxed type is it safe to use `==/!=` while comparing Character types?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Character c1 = 'd';
        Character c2 = (char) getInt();

        System.out.println(c1 == c2);
    }

    public static int getInt() {

        return 100;
    }
```

The following works as expected (true). However, are there cases where comparing Character with same value using `==` would lead to false? (Hence, do we have to use '.equals()' while comparing boxed primitive types?

Comment: Trivially `new Character('a') == new Character('a')` is false. Yes you should use `equals` when comparing reference types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is 128==128 false but 127==127 is true when comparing Integer wrappers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-is-128-128-false-but-127-127-is-true-when-comparing-integer-wrappers-in-ja)

Comment: It is never a good idea to use `==` with objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's not safe. You must use `equals()`.

Demonstration:

```
System.out.println(Character.valueOf('Ü') == Character.valueOf('Ü'));
// -> false
```

Note that if you use autoboxing or `Character.valueOf()`, then some characters (ASCII characters) are cached and the same `Character` instance is reused, so `==` may return `true` for the same value:

```
System.out.println(Character.valueOf('A') == Character.valueOf('A'));
// -> true (on my machine)
```

But it doesn't work for all characters, and it won't work if you call the deprecated `new Character(...)` explicitly.

Comment: Quote from `java.lang.Character#valueOf(char)` comment: "This method will always cache values in the range `\u0000` to `\u007F`, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range". The code itself, however, does not include any "other values".

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use code points, not `char`/`Character`.

```
"d".codePointAt( 0 ) == 100  // true.
```

## Details

The [Answer by Alex Shesterov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69499616/642706) is correct. But bigger picture, you should not be using `Character` objects.

### `Character` is broken

The `Character` class is a wrapper class for the primitive type `char`. The `char`/`Character` type is legacy as of Java 2, and is essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, it is physically **incapable of representing most characters**.

For example, try running:

```
 System.out.println( Character.valueOf( '' ) ) ;
```

### Code points

Instead, when working with individual characters, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers. In Java that means using the `int`/`Integer` type.

If you look around classes such as `String`, `StringBuilder`, and `Character` you will find `codePoint` methods.

Let's revise your code snippet. We will change the names to be more descriptive. We switch out `Character` and `char` usage for mere `int` primitive integers. As such, we can compare our `int` values using `==` or `!=`.

```java
package work.basil.text;

public class App7
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        int codePointOf_LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_D = "d".codePointAt( 0 ); // Annoying zero-based index counting, not ordinal.
        int codePoint2 = getInt();

        boolean sameCharacter = ( codePointOf_LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_D == codePoint2 );  // Comparing `int` primitives with double-equals. 
        System.out.println( sameCharacter );
    }

    public static int getInt ()
    {
        return 100;  // Code point 100 is LATIN SMALL LETTER D, `d`. 
    }
}
```

When run:

> true

Of course, if you use [auto-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) or otherwise mix the wrapper class `Integer` with the primitive `int`, then the same explanation in [that other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69499616/642706) applies here too.

- Compare `Integer` object to `Integer` object by calling [`Integer#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) or [`Objects.equals( Object a , Object b )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) rather than using `==`.
- Compare `int` primitive to `int` primitive using `==` or calling [`Integer.compare( int x , int y )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)).

Comment: There is nothing broken about `char` and `Character`. The legacy of Java 2 is that they are 16-bit. If Java were to be designed today, they would be 8-bit as in Go. In that case Java Strings would be UTF-8 encoded instead of UTF-16 encoded. UTF-8 encoding is more compact than UTF-16.

Comment: The concern for memory efficiency even made Java developers devise an alternative internal representation for the String class. Traditionally it was always UTF-16 but now String will try to use an 8-bit Latin-1 encoding if possible.