# java Map with Integer value comparison

Tags: java

With the below code, when comparing the `Integer` value for a given key in a hashmap. at a borderline `126` vs `127`, the comparison returns different results. I'm wondering why will java behave this way?

```java
Map<Character, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Character, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
int n = 127;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    map1.put('c', map1.getOrDefault('c', 1)+1);
    map2.put('c', map2.getOrDefault('c', 1)+1);
}
System.out.println(map1.get('c') == map2.get('c')); // print true if n = 126, print false if n = 127
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is 128==128 false but 127==127 is true when comparing Integer wrappers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-is-128-128-false-but-127-127-is-true-when-comparing-integer-wrappers-in-ja)

Comment: Don't compare objects with `==` only if you want to check identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it's caching by JVM. In other words for all values `[-128; 128)`. `Integer.valueOf(i)` will return the **same** `Integer` instance.

```java
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Comment: Is that source code from OpenJDK? I suggest acknowledging the source, and linking to original.

Comment: Yes, this is a code from jdk